# Run a Bash Script automatically upon login

Tags: bash, unix, centos

I wrote a script that sends the date and username of the person who logs in to a log file to keep a record of who has logged in.  I am wondering how can you set this script to execute automatically when a user logs in rather than have to manually run it in the terminal. NOTE: the USERNAME is the current user that is logged in.

my code:

```
#!/bin/bash

printf "$(date) $HOSTNAME booted!\n" >> /home/USERNAME/boot.log
```

Comment: Are there any security considerations? Do you trust the user? In particular -- is it all right if the user has the ability to disable the logging, or to tamper with an existing record of his/her logins?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

A more elegant way to solve this problem is to read from log files that are already being written and cannot be changed by the user. No one could say it better than [Bjørne Malmanger's in his answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/9674407/187273):

> I wouldn't trust the user to GIVE you the information. As root you
>   TAKE it ;-)

A nice way to do this is the `last` command, which is great because it neatly displays all logins: Graphical, console and SSH.

```
last
```

A less elegant but still secure way is to do a grep on /var/log/auth.log. On my Gnome/Ubuntu system I can use this to track graphical logins:

```
grep "session opened for user USERNAME"
```

The right pattern for your machine needs to be found for each login type: graphical, console and SSH. This is cumbersome, but you might need to do it if you need information that goes further back than `last` reaches.

To directly answer your question:

You can modify the script like this to get the username

```
#!bin/bash
printf "$(date) $HOSTNAME booted!\n" >> /home/$(whoami)/boot.log
```

And add this line to /etc/profile

```
. /path/to/script.sh
```

This is not secure though because the user will be able to edit his own log

Comment: I'd keep away from the bashrc files. They will log every time a new shell is opened and be filled quickly if someone uses tabs in xterm or GNU Screen.

Comment: @gpojd: Good point. Know any alternatives, aside tracking auth.log?

Comment: I think it would work fine in /etc/profile. It only gets run when a new login occurs, not when a new shell is opened.

Comment: i found that if you edit  the etc/rc.d/rc.local script it will allow the script to run each time the system boots up and logs in.

Comment: @JasonGagnon: Isn't rc.local run as root before login?

Comment: i believe so, but that's how my professor wanted the assignment to be to be run.

Comment: JasonGagnon: You could parse the log files into a different format in rc.local, but logging when rc.local gets called says nothing about who booted the machine.

Answer (score 4):

Why don't you use the `last` command?

I wouldn't trust the user to GIVE you the information. As root you TAKE it ;-)

Answer (score 3):

Put it in ~/.bash_profile. It will be run each time they log in.

More information is available at [the women's rights page (i.e. `man bash`)](http://linux.die.net/man/1/bash).

Answer (score 0):

There is already a script that will run automatically run when you log into Linux. This is the .bashrc file located in your home directory.

Any commands you put here will run. You can also call other scripts from within this .bashrc file.
type in:

```
nano ~/.bashrc
```